# Is it possible to expose all attributes from a loaded module from a new module?

Tags: python

I am writing an autograder for a class that I am teaching and the grader needs to be able to support many different online learning platform platforms, each with different file structures, etc. I don't necessarily know ahead of time what the student will name the file that is uploaded. My solution is to write the code that grades the students' submissions once and then I'll plug in a module that is specific to each platform to handle getting the student's file.
I.e. my grader files have a format like this:

```
import student_submission

# Grade the thing
```

And I will substitute in the appropriate `student_submission` module depending on the platform I am using. With one platform that I am using, the student is allowed to upload a file with an arbitrary name, and I don't want to force the students to rename their files a certain way. With help from other questions on stack overflow, I have a `student_submission.py` file that looks like this:

```
import importlib.util

# ...

# The following code loads the student submission module
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("student", student_submission_path)
student = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(student)
```

However, with this, I would have to write `from student_submission import student` in my grader file instead of writing `import student_submission`, which I suppose isn't too big of an inconvenience, but if possible I would just like to import the `student_submission` module. Is it possible for me to somehow expose everything that is contained inside of the `student` module from the `student_submission` module?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `from student_submission import *`

---

Edit: Since OP has updated the requirement in the discussion, the alternative approach is

`from student_submission import student as student_submission`

Comment: This is essentially the same as saying `from student_submission import student`

Comment: @bl5eebryce: No, it is not the same. It imports *everything* public in `student_submission` not just `student`. Note I am not saying it's a good idea to `import *`.

Comment: @martineau That's true, but later in my code, I delete all other public attributes except for `student`, so in my case it is essentially the same. I should have been a little more clear. Either way, it doesn't answer the question because the attributes I want `student_submission` to expose are currently inside of `student` (i.e. `student.compute_svd()`) and I want them to be inside of `student_submission` (i.e. `student_submission.compute_svd()` instead of `student_submission.student.compute_svd()`)

Comment: In that case, you may do `from student_submission import student as student_submission`